# How to add a simple 8dp header/footer to Android's RecyclerView?

Tags: android, margin, padding, android-recyclerview

Is there a way to add a simple header/footer to a RecyclerView?

Here you can see what I've got. The first Card touches the Toolbar
[image: This is what I've got]
And here you can see what I would like to achieve:

8dp Padding between the bottom and the Card. 
[image: This is what I want to have]

Methods I tried so far:

Use a header view in my recyclerview. But I think it is very inefficient to do this for every recyclerview.

use a 8dp top margin which results in the problem that the recyclerview has white bars on top/bottom when scrolling.

add a padding to the list item which results in different margins between the outer and inner cards.

I'm sure that there is a simple solution which I don't know so far.

Answer (score 443, accepted):

Adding a top padding and setting `clipToPadding` to false will do the trick.
Something like this:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Works for the top, but for some reason not the bottom.

Comment: Which version of the support library are you using? Setting paddingBottom works fine for me.

Comment: doesnt work for me either on api 23. I am trying   android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"

Comment: @Benjamin, have you found any solution to paddingBottom?

Comment: This answer is correct, a better explanation can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33754618/1932522

Comment: paddingBottom Works for me, recyclerview-v7-25.3.1

Comment: @eskalera check my answer for paddingBottom

Comment: This solution clips the scrollbar, though. Any solutions to that?

Comment: Edit: to prevent this add `android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"`

Comment: Wonderful answer! `android:clipToPadding` does the trick. I needed a custom implementation such that, my`RecyclerViewRecyclerView` has padding from the title above, but can be seen scrolling title which has alpha added to it.

Comment: Thnx,best answerr

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a RecyclerView with a `layout_weight`, and `paddingBottom` is not working for you, making sure you set the layout_height to `0dp`! Otherwise, strangely, paddingTop works but paddingBottom does not:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
```

Comment: Setting the height to 0dp makes the view disappear. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Just remove weight="1" and set layout_height to match_parent